Using hmmlearn to make a linear hidden markov model
I want to use a Hidden Markov Model architecture where each state can only stay in itself, or go to the next state. All other options have a probability of zero.
I want to fit data with this model, such that the resulting model answers the constraints as well.
I am using the hmmlearn library with python, and need to work with a 10 state Gaussian Mixture Model. How can this be implemented? I don't see any information in the docs, and I can't find any guarantee that the fit will preserve any initial condition.

You need to constrain some (many) of the transition probabilities to be zero. It seems this can be done by creating a custom HMM class in hmmlearn. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73759411/9586385 (and the Github repo it links).

I found this, but I think it would be wildly inefficient to zero out all the values except those that lie on the main diagonal and the one next to it on every iteration. Is there maybe a faster way to do this? I'm worried my already awful code will have trouble surviving
